# Creating Period for Multi Quarter Timespan in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Many companies release quarterly financial data which maps nicely to a Pandas Period:

`p = Period('2012Q1', freq='Q-DEC')`

which in the filings would be labeled "Three Months Ended March 31, 2012".

However some financial data is released in the form: "Nine Months Ended September 30, 2005".
How would I create a Period object for the "Nine Months Ended September 30, 2005"?

Another way of expressing that period would be "2005(Q1-Q3)".

I asked: [Extract Quarterly Data from Multi Quarter Periods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17976074/extract-quarterly-data-from-multi-quarter-periods)

Comment: This seems like an ambiguous metric (since 12 isn't divisible by 9), saying that I think there is a github issue for support for similar more bespoke periods... but can't find it https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues

Comment: I am not sure that ambiguous is the right word. Nothing about "this is the income made by company X over a nine month period" is ambiguous. Certainly it will make it difficult to have a series of 9 month observations since they will not end on year boundaries.

Comment: perhaps I mean not well-defined 2012Q1 Q-DEC completely defines period, not sure you can say the same about 9 month periods. But yeah if you just have the start month and year it'd be well defined. Could you do this easier using some kind of rolling sum (of 3 Qs)?

Comment: Ultimately what I am trying to accomplished is taking a number of earnings filings which may be of the form: 2005(Q1), 2005(Q1-Q2), 2005(Q1-Q3), 2005(Q1-Q4) (aka 2005), which are overlapping periods and extracting the quarterly values.

Comment: That seems like a sensible thing to do, not sure how to answer in current form, perhaps make a new question (as it's different to this one) and give some pretend data (for some of Q1 Q1-2 overlapping) :)