# Extract Quarterly Data from Multi Quarter Periods

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

Public companies in the US make quarterly filings (10-Q) and yearly filings (10-K). In most cases they will file three 10Qs per year and one 10K.

In most cases, the quarterly filings (10Qs) contain quarterly data. For example, "revenue for the three months ending March 31, 2005."

The yearly filings will often only have year end sums. For example: "revenue for the twelve months ending December 31, 2005."

In order to get the value for Q4 of 2005, I need to take the yearly data and subtract the values for each of the quarters (Q1-Q3).

In some cases, each of the quarterly data is expressed as year to date. For example, the first quarterly filing is "revenue for the three months ending March 31, 2005." The second is "revenue for the six months ending June 30, 2005." The third "revenue for the nine months ending September 30, 2005." The yearly is like above, "revenue for the twelve months ending December 31, 2005." This represents a generalization of the above issues in which the desire is to extract quarterly data which can be accomplished by repeated subtraction of the previous period data.

My question is what is the best way in pandas to accomplish this quarterly data extraction?

There a large number of fields (revenue, profit, exposes, etc) per period.

A related question that I asked in regards to how to express this period data in pandas: [Creating Period for Multi Quarter Timespan in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973156/creating-period-for-multi-quarter-timespan-in-pandas)

Here is some example data of the first problem (three 10Qs and one 10K which only has year end data):

10Q:

- http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1174922/000119312512225309/d326512d10q.htm#tx326512_4
- http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1174922/000119312512347659/d360762d10q.htm#tx360762_3
- http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1174922/000119312512463380/d411552d10q.htm#tx411552_3

10K:

- http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1174922/000119312513087674/d459372d10k.htm#tx459372_29

Calcbench refers to this problem: http://www.calcbench.com/Home/userGuide: "Q4 calculation: Companies often do not report Q4 data, rather opting to report full year data instead. We’ll automatically calculate it for you. Data in blue is calculated.

There will be multiple years of data and for each year I want to calculate the missing fourth quarter:

```
         2012Q2  2012Q3  2012Y  2013Q1  2013Q2  2013Q3  2013Y
Revenue       1       1      1       1       1       1      1
Expense      10      10     10      10      10      10     10
```

Comment: Do you think you could you give some dummy data?

Answer (score 0):

You could define a function to subtract the quarterly totals from the annual number, and then apply the function to each row, storing the result in a new column.

```
In [2]: df
Out[2]:
         Annual  Q1  Q2  Q3
Revenue      18   3   4   5
Expense      17   2   3   4

In [3]: def calc_Q4(row):
   ...:     return row['Annual'] - row['Q1'] - row['Q2'] - row['Q3']

In [4]: df['Q4'] = df.apply(calc_Q4, axis = 1)

In [5]: df
Out[5]:
         Annual  Q1  Q2  Q3  Q4
Revenue      18   3   4   5   6
Expense      17   2   3   4   8
```

Answer (score 0):

I work for Calcbench.

I wrote an API for Calcbench and have example of getting SEC data into Pandas dataframes, https://www.calcbench.com/home/api.

You would need to sign up for Calcbench to use it.